# Occasional excessive IOWait freezes computer - how to diagnose?

Tags: filesystem, performance

I have a very slow SSD on an eeepc900A, and it occasionally freezes the OS (even the mouse pointer) with system monitor showing excessive IOWait.  How can I diagnose what is causing this and should the system allow it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install the package `iotop`

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

and run the program to see what has high io demands at those moments.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately iotop tells me:

CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT not enabled in kernel, cannot determine SWAPIN and IO %

Any way around that?

Comment: That said, iotop -o seems to give me all I need to know for now.

Comment: @themuddler: I am not sure if the changed kernel will be backported, but in Maverick this kernel configuration will be enabled.

Comment: Even without CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT enabled in the kernel, you can still see which applications read or write the most (try left & right arrow to select the "sort column")

Answer (score 2):

There's a good ServerFault answere [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/12679/can-anyone-explain-precisely-what-iowait-is)